# FM Radio API and Trigger Radio On Off

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone-silverlight, fm-radio

no fm radio api found for windows phone 8.1  , and UWP
and how trigger radio on/off

i found 'using Microsoft.Devices.Radio' but not works on windows phone 8.1 only works for windows phone 7

Comment: Just importing namespace doesn't work.

Comment: yes, unable to found required namespace

Comment: ha ha who say no i got the trick -- now new fm radio app will be available in store wait

Comment: Could you please buy windows phone for me? need to see your app :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. Make a new project in Visual Studio for Windows Phone 8.0/8.1 Silverlight App after installing the installing the appropriate sdk.

and also create two project with win phone silverlight and class and another UWP and reference it in UWP app , now we able to use silverlight api in uwp

Answer (score 1):

In UWP it is now `Windows.Devices.Radios`, you can refer to the [Radio class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.devices.radios.radio.aspx), but FM is not currently available. You can refer to [RadioKind enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.devices.radios.radiokind.aspx)

[image]

Seems this will be supported in the future, I think you may submit a request to add this new feature for development through the Windows Feedback tool.

Comment: ha ha who say no i got the trick -- now new fm radio app will be available in store wait

Comment: @ShubhamSahu, congratulations!

Comment: @ShubhamSahu Could you please buy windows phone for me? need to see your app :P

Comment: @Imad goto this link app is ready https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/p/fm-radio-tune/9nblggh42q75

Comment: @ShubhamSahu, I saw your answer, your question is about win8.1 app and UWP app, they are WinRT based app, and your solution is creating a Windows Phone 8.0/8.1 Silverlight App, they are totally different.